# Admob causing IPv6 App Store Rejection

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I received the following message for my Apple App Store review:

Your app crashed on iPad or iPhone running iOS 11.2.5 connected to an IPv6 network during our review.
We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

This is part of my crash log:

```
Timestamp               Thread     Type        Activity             PID
2018-03-25 07:43:18.7992 -0700  0x1600a 1024 0x0 6376 AssertionServices: BKSWorkspace created.
2018-03-25 07:43:18.9009 -0700  0x1600a 1024 0x0 6376 AccessibilitySettingsLoader: Loading settings loader: (system: 0)
2018-03-25 07:43:18.9050 -0700  0x1600a 1024 0x0 6376 AccessibilitySettingsLoader: AXSettingsLoader told to start
2018-03-25 07:43:18.9210 -0700  0x1602e 1024 0x0 6376 FrontBoardServices: [FBSScene] [.MOEDict] Created client agent: <UIApplicationSceneClientAgent: 0x1c0018640>
2018-03-25 07:43:19.0010 -0700  0x1600a 1024 0x0 6376 StoreServices: SSVApplicationCapabilitiesRequest: Beginning background task
2018-03-25 07:43:19.0032 -0700  0x1600a 1024 0x0 6376 StoreServices: SSVApplicationCapabilitiesRequest: Took power assertion: SSVApplicationCapabilitiesRequest
2018-03-25 07:43:19.0212 -0700  0x16027 1024 0x0 6376 StoreServices: SSVApplicationCapabilitiesRequest: Released power assertion: SSVApplicationCapabilitiesRequest
2018-03-25 07:43:19.3979 -0700  0x1600a 1024 0x0 6376 libsystem_network.dylib: nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked Starting host resolution www.google.com:0, flags 0x4000d000 proto 0
2018-03-25 07:43:19.4221 -0700  0x1602d 1024 0x0 6376 libsystem_network.dylib: nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554) hostname=www.google.com. addr=::.0 ttl=60
.
.
.
2018-03-25 07:43:21.0140 -0700  0x1603e 1024 0x0 6376 libsystem_network.dylib: nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554) hostname=googleads.g.doubleclick.net. addr=::.0 ttl=60
```

Take note at the last 2 line. Is this issued caused by Admob? How to fix it?

Comment: Who downvoted and voted to close this question? Please give a reason. If you do not know how to solve this issue, you may leave this question.

Comment: Have you tested your app on a pure ipv6 network to see if that is the issue?

Comment: Test your app in a ipv6 network. You can find it here [Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1). This might not be your problem also. If any crash occur they always write the same thing. The reason of your crash could be different than that.

Comment: I do not own any iOS device. I only test my app on simulator. So I can't test my app on IP6.

Comment: Have you used any reachability file in the project?